# 504 Gateway Timeout from an IIS Server

Tags: iis-7.5, http-status-code-504

I am using a web Server based on IIS,I am using an Infor Application which is trying to fetch data from the Web Server. However when there is a lot of data and the query runs more than 60 seconds, i get a Gateway Timeout Error(504).

Where do i set the configuration to increase till say 2 minutes  or 5 minutes? Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If as the other answer suggests, you are using ARR, there is another undocumented setting which often causes 502's

https://serverfault.com/questions/259857/why-does-web-farm-framework-keep-marking-my-wfes-as-unhealthy/522774#522774

http://forums.iis.net/t/1183539.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have ARR installed. If you do, you can change the timeout setting by following these steps:

1. Open IIS Manager.
2. Open Application Request Routing Cache.
3. Open Server Proxy Settings... from the Actions menu.
4. Increase the Time-out (seconds) to a bigger value.

Another place this could be set is under Server Farms in IIS Manager. Choose the Server Farm and click Proxy. Set the time-out (seconds) to a larger value.